# Как считать stream.Readable в buffer?

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных

Вот сам поток:

[image: Сам поток:]

Задача - считать его в буфер (про наличие библиотек знаю, хочется понимать саму суть).

Пытался так:

```
  let body;

  steam.on('data', (chunk) => {
    debugger
    body += chunk;
  });
```

Debugger не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по картинке, вопрос про чтение [stream.Readable](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable)

#### Как его прочитать

```
const chunks = [];
stream.on('data', (x) => chunks.push(x));
stream.on('end', () => {
  // закончилось чтение потока
  // можем склеить все чанки (они тоже буфер) в один буфер
  // и что-то с ним сделать
  const buf = Buffer.concat(chunks);
}
```

#### Что важно не забывать?

Во время работы с потоком возможны ошибки, обрывы, закрытия потока. Нужно писать обработчики на `close`, `error`.

---

Как завернуть чтение буфера в асинхронную функцию?

Способ 1 - Consuming readable streams with async iterators

With the support of async generators and iterators in JavaScript, async generators are effectively a first-class language-level stream construct at this point

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {

  const stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, './csv/8.csv'));

  const chunks = [];
  for await (const chunk of stream) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  }

  const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  console.log(`bufferLength=${buffer.length}`);

  stream.close();

})();
```

Async iterators register a permanent error handler on the stream to prevent any unhandled post-destroy errors.

Способ 2

```
// @ts-check
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {

  const stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, './csv/8.csv'));

  /** @type {Buffer} */
  const buffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const chunks = [];
    stream.on('data', (x) => chunks.push(x));
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
    stream.on('error', reject);
    stream.on('close', reject);

  });

  console.log(`bufferLength=${buffer.length}`);

})();
```

```bsh
$ ls -la src/csv-stream/csv/8.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 x  staff  5683264  7 окт 02:01 src/csv-stream/csv/8.csv

$ node src/csv-stream/read.js 
bufferLength=5683264
```

Comment: А в чем тут может быть проблема? https://prnt.sc/wv4crl А вот и сам поток: https://prnt.sc/wv4mb1

Comment: я не понимаю что ты подразумеваешь под словом "проблема"